# Conflicting answers both claiming to be right

Tags: definite-integrals

My book lists the answer as: http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/calculus-4th-edition-chapter-5.3-solutions-9780495557425

But I keep getting 5/3, and both Symbolab and Wolfram agree with my answer.

Which answer is right?

Comment: I looked over your book's answer and found no mistakes. Can you link to your calculation of the value using Wolfram? (The software can interpret inputs quite differently from what you intend.) Also, can you show how you did it?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/EHHAx

My calculation method: https://imgur.com/a/rSkur

Comment: The problem in the book was to integrate $x^2-3,$ not $x^3-3.$

Comment: Ahhh, you've got $x^3$ in lieu of $x^2$. Common mistake!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+(x%5E2-3)+from+x%3D-2+to+3

Comment: You "keep getting $5/3$", and post a solution giving $5/4$?!